# pushViewController for same instance - only for animation purpose

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, single-instance

I am having single table view in a view controller. That table view lists the countries first. When I click on a country(row), it has to push the same view controller's view with cities under that country. I need to see the slide animation, which we usally get while pushing views in navigator.

Is it possible to use the pushViewController for the same view controller by calling the tableView reloadData with city data (This should happen when country is selected) ?

Please let me know whether it is possible..

Thanks in advance..
Raj

Comment: Sorry for this question! As I am a very beginner I don't know the actual flow of the view controllers. I am clear now. Please never mind this question.

Comment: Voting not to close, but please provide some code on your question that demonstrates what you've done so far so people can understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't push twice the same instance in the UINavigationController: "This object cannot be an instance of tab bar controller and it must not already be on the navigation stack." Instead you could allocate another instance of your UITableView or design a new class to handle cities.